# How can I speed up the Pandas.index apply?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create vector/array of when DataFrame index, which is a DateTimeIndex, is between hours of 8 and 14.

This works but is very slow:

```
permitted = flose.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: 1 if 8 <= x.hour <= 14 else 0)
```

I am tried variations of this but always get errors:

```
permitted = np.where(8 <= flose.index.values.hour <= 14 ,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
permitted = ((8 <= flose.index.to_series().dt.hour) & (flose.index.to_series().dt.hour <= 14)).astype(int)
```

Comment: I get:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'

Comment: Do you need the & in there?

Comment: Yes, to enforce the result is also <= 14

Comment: would np.logical_and be slower? It is more readable

Comment: @ManInMoon I dont think it would be a lot slower, if any